# How to cache normal and mobile view for same URL in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, caching, mobile, url-routing

I'm running a check if the user is browsing on a mobile device or desktop, and based on that I call the normal_view for the given URL, or mobile_view for the same URL. So the URL and the controller function are the same, just the view is different (mobile or desktop).
I use Codeigniter built-in Output cache, but if the first user that will open the page, loads the normal_view, it puts it into output cache, and till the cache expire, only that view is loaded no matter if the user is browsing from Mobile or PC.

How can I solve this without making different URLs for mobile and desktop version? Is there any way that I can cache the views separately?

Comment: Hi @MarkC Did you get it to work? Need to implement cache in a site using codeigniter and I'm asking myself how to

Answer (score 0):

By using User Agent Class  Library in Codeigniter  we can implement like that

Ex:

```
 $this->load->library('user_agent');
    if ($this->agent->is_mobile('iphone'))
    {
        $this->load->view('iphone/home');  //iphone view page
    }
    else if ($this->agent->is_mobile())
    {
        $this->load->view('mobile/home'); //mobile view page
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('web/home'); // web page view
    }
```

Note: My Suggestion is can you please use any CSS Frame work like Bootstrap 
no need to develop separate for mobile views.It can take care based on device sizes

http://getbootstrap.com

```
Bootstrap easily and efficiently scales your websites and applications with a single code base, from phones to tablets to desktops with CSS media queries.
```

Comment: You have misunderstood my question. What you wrote me is already done and working. The design shouldn't be responsive because the mobile site is more like an mobile application, but that's not the subject here.
My logic is almost the same as your, but if you use $this->output->cache(n), the first view that will be opened will be cached, and after no matter what the agent is, the URL will be cached and it will display the first loaded URL until the cache expire, and then it will cache the URL again only with the first opened view.